# How to add more honey to my honey ale?

Tags: first-time-brewer, ale, honey

I'm trying to figure out the best way to go about adding more honey to my honey ale. I recently purchased the White House Honey Ale kit from Northern Brewer and I'm seeing several reviews saying the honey flavor doesn't come through very well. It's a 1 gallon brew kit and has no secondary fermentation.

When/how would I go about adding more honey without the concern of the yeast just turning it into alchohol and leaving behind none of the honey flavor?

Answer (score 1):

Weyermanns Abbey Malt adds honey flavour and aroma. There are other Honey Malts available, but I have not used them.

Add the malt to your mash or do a steep (depending on if your kit is all grain or extract).

Answer (score 0):

Honey is 100% sugar and will be entirely consumed by the yeast in your beer.

I've made mead a couple times with different varieties of honey. The honey flavor left after the fermentation is a very mild and dry sweetness, nothing like the flavor of raw honey.